# Android+Robolectric Test ERROR "java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!"

Tags: android, maven, testing

I have written a test with Eclipse ADT + maven + Robolectric as below.

```
public void testPostToConnectionsCorrect() {

    setCorrectIP();
    activity.postToConnections();
    Mockito.verify(mainWebView).postUrl(Mockito.anyString(), EncodingUtils.getBytes(Mockito.anyString(), "UTF-8"));
}

private void setCorrectIP() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Robolectric.getShadowApplication().getApplicationContext(),
            ConnectionsContainerActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("IPAddress", "135.127.21.183");
    activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(ConnectionsContainerActivity.class).withIntent(i).create().visible().get();
    mainWebView = Mockito.mock(WebView.class);
    activity.setMainWebView(mainWebView);
}
```

But get a error when I run "maven install" as follwing:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.744 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.ncr.cxp.client.connections.container.test.ConnectionsContainerActivityTest
testPostToConnectionsCorrect(com.ncr.cxp.client.connections.container.test.ConnectionsContainerActivityTest)  Time elapsed: 7.65 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at org.apache.http.util.EncodingUtils.getBytes(EncodingUtils.java:7)
    at com.ncr.cxp.client.connections.container.ConnectionsContainerActivity.postToConnections(ConnectionsContainerActivity.java:166)
    at com.ncr.cxp.client.connections.container.ConnectionsContainerActivity.onCreate(ConnectionsContainerActivity.java:150)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at org.fest.reflect.method.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:112)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:116)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:256)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:111)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:123)
    at com.ncr.cxp.client.connections.container.test.ConnectionsContainerActivityTest.setCorrectIP(ConnectionsContainerActivityTest.java:79)
    at com.ncr.cxp.client.connections.container.test.ConnectionsContainerActivityTest.testPostToConnectionsCorrect(ConnectionsContainerActivityTest.java:70)
```

It seems the robolectric cannot catch this "stub" exception and run the test in VM. I tried some solutions in the past discussions but none of them works.

PS: I have also write other tests in the same project with robolectric and they are fine. Only this test has problem.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the "RoboGuice" in the dependency as fix it.